# Visual Studio - Client Objects & Events drop down list missing?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have no idea how this option got turned off but...

**Showing Client Objects & Events:**
[image]

**Missing Client Objects & Events:**
[image]

How do I turn this option back on so that it's showing again?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Go to `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> General` and make sure `Navigation Bar` is checked.

Comment: Yeah, this didn't work for me. Any project done in VB is fine, C# the Client Objects and Events is missing. I've checked All, C# and VB language settings for the Navigation Bar. All are checked.

Comment: Did you try closing and re-opening VS after enabling the setting? That did it for me.

Comment: HOW DARE THEY DO THIS. Default-MISSING in VS 2022.

Thank you for your solution. If I didn't know better I would say MSFT is hellbent on making people NOT be able to do stuff in 2022.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that you should enable "View all properties" checkbox at the bottom left of the properties window, so you can edit the "text editor" settings, because is hidden by default.